# Automatic BIN Range Update/detection service

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, payment-processing, payment-services

I am currently managing a software estate that stores card bin ranges in a table for card checking.

This currently means that we have to manually update the bin range table on a regular basis to ensure it can cater for new cards.

I am wanting to automate this process, is there an easy way to automatically update the bin ranges or an online API service we can use? I did find: http://www.binchecker.org/ however it was last updated in 2011 and seems like it has died out.

or is there an easier wayto detect without needing BIN ranges? i have read that the start number determins the card type? I have seen other questions posted here that link to BIN lists (for example the barclaycard pdf, wikipedia) but that still requires manual input.

EDIT http://www.binchecker.org/ appears to be an old site https://www.bindb.com is the new updated site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an automated service, and many of the online lists/services that attempt this are woefully out of date (I just checked a random MasterCard range 557548 against bindb for example, and found it not listed)

The official lists are managed by ANSI [www.ansi.org/iin](http://www.ansi.org/iin/) and distributed monthly by the American Banking Association. You would need to qualify yourself as a Payment Service Provider (or higher) to have access to these lists.

For the most part though you shouldn't need to convert the IIN (or BIN) to a card scheme. You just submit the full card number to your payment gateway and let them do the work.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the official IIN source. In the case of my  company that accepts payments worldwide, we use multiple payment gateways so knowing the card scheme ahead of time allows us to route to the quickest & cheapest payment gateway. We use BinDB but there database update occurs only twice a year

Answer (score -1):

Well, according to MasterCard this particular BIN 557548 is not in use, so it's not assigned.